# Passing javascript/Jquery array to php through a form

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, forms, variables

So I have a jquery function that checks what checkboxes are checked and puts the id's in an array. Now that array gets passed to the value of a hidden input field and later submitted to the php script. What happens is, it looks like it puts every value in the first index instead of individual indexes.

This is the function for getting the id's of the checked checkboxes in the array. I read about push and so far I understood that push actually pushes a value to a new index?

```
$(".article-checkbox:checked").each(function() {
            multipleCheckboxes.push($(this).val());
        });
```

My form:

```
<form id="publish-form" method="post" action="publisharticle.php" onsubmit="getMultipleCheckboxValues()">
    <input type="hidden" value="" name="checkbox-value2[]" id="checkbox-value2">
    li><input type="submit" value="Publish"></li>
</form>
```

the function onsubmit:

```
function getMultipleCheckboxValues(){
    getValueUsingClass();
    $("#checkbox-value2").val(multipleCheckboxes);
}

function getValueUsingClass(){
        /* declare an checkbox array */
        var chkArray = [];
        var i = 0;

        /* look for all checkboes that have a class 'chk' attached to it and check if it was checked */
        $(".article-checkbox:checked").each(function() {
            chkArray.push($(this).val());
            multipleCheckboxes.push($(this).val());
            i++;
        });

        /* we join the array separated by the comma */
        var selectedOne = chkArray[0];
        var selected;
        selected = chkArray.join(',') + ",";

        /* check if there is selected checkboxes, by default the length is 1 as it contains one single comma */
        if(selected.length > 1){
            oneCheckbox = selectedOne;
        //alert("Please at least one of the checkbox" + selectedCheckboxes); 
    }else{
        alert("Please at least one of the checkbox");   
    }
}
```

and php:

```
$checks =  $_POST['checkbox-value2'];

echo $checks[0];
```

Now in PHP I want to iterate through an array instead of a string. Lets say I check checkbox one and two the php code above echo's 1,2 even though I chose index 0. I also tried:

```
var i = 0;
$(".article-checkbox:checked").each(function() {
            chkArray.push($(this).val());
            multipleCheckboxes[i].push($(this).val());
            i++;
        });
```

Comment: Whats the output of `var_dump($checks);`

Comment: array(1) { [0]=> string(3) "1,2" }

Comment: and the values of those checkboxes where 1 and 2, correct? and now you want to iterate through the 1 and 2 etc

Comment: `name="checkbox-value2[]"` what are the `[]` for? As it seems, both checkboxes were selected, so you should be able to iterate over them after splitting, eg via [`explode()`](http://php.net/explode)

Comment: Yes I want the values 1 and 2 to be in different indexes.

Comment: then just do `foreach(explode(",", $checks) as $check) {echo $check;} ` and then you would be iterating through those values

Comment: the [] is for passing an array through a form.

Comment: It doesn't echo anything out by that

Comment: sorry explode(",", $checks[0])

Comment: Thanks I think that works, still I wonder isn't there a normal way of passing an array through? Or is that a normal way to iterate?

Comment: DaViDa, I submitted an answer with a shorter and much better way to accomplish what you want. sure you can update/rename some elements, hope that helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a better way of submitting a form data as key => value
to a PHP script.

HTML

```
<form id="publish-form" method="post">
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1"> Checkbox1
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox2"> Checkbox2
     <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox3"> Checkbox3
    <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

JavaScript

```
var items = {};

$('button').click(function () {
    $('#public-form input').each(function () {
        if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
            items[$(this).id] = $(this).val();
        }
    });

    $.post('/publisharticle.php', items).done(function (data) {
        // response from php script
        console.log(data);
    });

});
```

PHP

```
foreach($_POST as $key => $value){
    echo $key . ": " . $value . "\n";
}
```

Comment: You could also use JSON.stringify(object) to send the js object as a single string and use json_decode on the back end to parse it.

Comment: lexmihaylov whats the point if he already received key and value for each input, stringify + decoding here only adds extra work for the front and the back end scripts :)